# Odd chirpy noise, not chain or pulleys

Tags: drivetrain, noise

So I have this familiar chirpy/twittery noise coming from drivetrain.  It is under load on a down push on left crank, per revolution, lighter pedaling less noticeable.  It's definitely not the usual chain or jockey wheels.  Latter having been stripped and bearings regreased.  Standard 1x Rival setup on a gravel bike, Easton EA90 crank with Sram Dub BB. Most likely suspect is BB.  Anyone had that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  It might help if you can add a video demonstrating this effect.  If you get someone to assist you with the video, maybe they can confirm it's coming from the crank/BB area which would also help narrow the issue down.

Comment: since it only happens the left downstroke, it could be a per-one-crank-revolution issue, since it doesn't occur with the load from the right downstroke. does the noise occur in the same left downstroke no matter what gear you are in?

Comment: Yes per revolution whatever gear. Another 100 miles on it yesterday, and now it's progressed to more of a bearing graunch, so pretty sure it's BB now/.  Wish it was hollowtech BB.  Have to source another tool now, goddamned 'standards' have gone ballistic in recent years.